# Python Web scraping: Xbox games

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very new to web scarping and I am trying to scrape the xbox website to get the `gameid`,`game name`,`game desc`, `game genre`, and `game tags`

The link to the website: [XBOX](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/all-games?cat=all)

My code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/all-games?cat=all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
games = []
for game in soup.find_all("div", class_="gameDivsWrapper x-hidden-focus"):
    print(game)
```

I am stuck after this, I don't know where to look for the above items.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is generated by ChatGPT,

I will try to give you some personal advice given my experience. If you would be willing to use Node.js, there are plenty of packages which can be used for scraping, and an Xbox Live API package which can help you authenticate and access the API more officially - which means you won't need to scrape at all. However the methods to get game info are not known to myself, so mileage may vary.

If you don't wish to use that, I have other advice:

Make sure you are selecting each game correctly. I am unfamiliar with using python, but essentially you are going to want to select those items with `#ContentBlockList_1 > div.thecatalog > div.gameList > div.gameDivsWrapper > div`

This will include some non-games, but this will allow you to loop through the divs and pull information that is embedded. It does not provide all of the information you are looking for, as for example:

```html
<div class="m-product-placement-item f-size-medium context-game gameDiv" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-bigid="9PP97VC2BL8H" data-releasedate="2023-06-05T23:00:00.0000000Z" data-msproduct="false" data-multiplayer="true" data-rating="MATURE 17+" data-ratingsystem="ESRB" data-listprice="69.99">
```

This element is missing the name and description. So within this div, you will have to select/parse additional properties, the name and description can be found under the class "pop-info". Hopefully this helps, trying ChatGPT answers has a similar rate of success.